# Level is deleting an item form my list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list

```
list={{{{2, 4}, {1}}, {3}}, {{{2, 4}, {3}}, {1}}, {{{1,2}, {3}}, {4}}, {{{1, 2}, {4}}, {3}}, {{{3, 1}, {2}}, {4}}, {{{3,1}, {4}}, {2}}}
```

I want to make it a list of list of lists, so I want to have the following list as a result

```
list={{{2, 4}, {1}, {3}}, {{2, 4}, {3}, {1}}, {{1,2}, {3}, {4}}, {{1, 2}, {4}, {3}}, {{3, 1}, {2}, {4}}, {{3,1}, {4}, {2}}}
```

I figure I would use `Level[list,{-3}]`, but the result deletes the last item in the nested list I want to have. The output I am getting is

```
{{{2, 4}, {1}}, {{2, 4}, {3}}, {{1, 2}, {3}}, {{1, 2}, {4}}, {{3, 1}, {2}}, {{3, 1}, {4}}}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list = {{{{2, 4}, {1}}, {3}}, {{{2, 4}, {3}}, {1}}, {{{1, 
      2}, {3}}, {4}}, {{{1, 2}, {4}}, {3}}, {{{3, 
      1}, {2}}, {4}}, {{{3, 1}, {4}}, {2}}};
Level[#, {-2}] & /@ list
```

Answer (score 4):

You can `Apply` `Append` at `Level` 1 :

```
Append @@@ list
```

> ```
> {{{2, 4}, {1}, {3}},
>  {{2, 4}, {3}, {1}}, 
>  {{1, 2}, {3}, {4}}, 
>  {{1, 2}, {4}, {3}},
>  {{3, 1}, {2}, {4}}, 
>  {{3, 1}, {4}, {2}}}
> ```

Looking at the levels using `ExpressionGraph` might help:

```
eg = ExpressionGraph[list, GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding"];

ticks = Thread[{Reverse[Union[GraphEmbedding[eg][[All, 2]]]], 
   Style[#, 16] &@Row[{"Level ", #}] & /@ List /@ Range[0, Depth[list] - 1]}];

labeling = AssociationThread[VertexList @ eg, 
   "Subexpression" /. (VertexList[eg] /. AnnotationValue[eg, AnnotationRules])];

Show[SetProperty[eg, { VertexLabelStyle -> 7,
    VertexLabels -> {v_ :>  Placed[labeling[v], After], 
      1 -> Placed[labeling[1], Above]}}], 
  Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], 
  FrameTicks -> {{None, ticks}, {None, None}}, ImageSize -> 1200]
```

[image]

Comment: Terrific! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
list =
  {{{{2, 4}, {1}}, {3}},
   {{{2, 4}, {3}}, {1}},
   {{{1, 2}, {3}}, {4}},
   {{{1, 2}, {4}}, {3}},
   {{{3, 1}, {2}}, {4}},
   {{{3, 1}, {4}}, {2}}};
```

Using `FlattenAt`

```
FlattenAt[1] /@ list
```

returns

```
{{{2, 4}, {1}, {3}}, 
 {{2, 4}, {3}, {1}}, 
 {{1, 2}, {3}, {4}}, 
 {{1, 2}, {4}, {3}}, 
 {{3, 1}, {2}, {4}}, 
 {{3, 1}, {4}, {2}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list =
  {{{{2, 4}, {1}}, {3}},
   {{{2, 4}, {3}}, {1}},
   {{{1, 2}, {3}}, {4}},
   {{{1, 2}, {4}}, {3}},
   {{{3, 1}, {2}}, {4}},
   {{{3, 1}, {4}}, {2}}};
```

---

Using `Replace` at level `1`:

```
Replace[list, {{a__}, b_} :> {a, b}, {1}]

{{{2, 4}, {1}, {3}}, 
 {{2, 4}, {3}, {1}}, 
 {{1, 2}, {3}, {4}}, 
 {{1, 2}, {4}, {3}}, 
 {{3, 1}, {2}, {4}}, 
 {{3, 1}, {4}, {2}}}
```

Or using `Apply` and `Join` at level `1`:

```
Apply[Join[#1, {#2}] &, list, {1}]

{{{2, 4}, {1}, {3}}, 
 {{2, 4}, {3}, {1}}, 
 {{1, 2}, {3}, {4}}, 
 {{1, 2}, {4}, {3}}, 
 {{3, 1}, {2}, {4}}, 
 {{3, 1}, {4}, {2}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list /. {{s___}, d_} :> {s, d}

{{{2, 4}, {1}, {3}}, {{2, 4}, {3}, {1}}, {{1, 2}, {3}, {4}}, {{1, 
   2}, {4}, {3}}, {{3, 1}, {2}, {4}}, {{3, 1}, {4}, {2}}}
```